# Is Splitting IDE hdds between Primary and Secondary faster?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, raid, pata

I'm doing RAID 0 on two IDE harddrives (yes, this is old hardware). Will the harddrives be faster if I attach them separately so that one is on the Primary IDE controller and the other is on the Secondary IDE controller? Or would it just be as good as having them both on the Primary IDE as master and slave?

Comment: Do take time to read the specs for the motherboard.  On one of my older systems the Primary IDE port would do 133MB/s but the second port would only operate at 66MB/s.

Comment: I didn't read the specs, but both controllers support UDMA 5, which I believe equals out to 133MB/s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well each IDE channel has a certain amount of bandwith - having a master and slave splits between them- so if you only have two drives, and two free channels, having one drive, as master on each and nothing else makes sense